# How to retrieve customer id from SID magento

Tags: magento-1.9, web-services

I want to retrieve session data in web services.I have SID in magento in the form 'enjgmb9m8pq2ij2jq3vcr0vln5'.I want to retrieve customer id from it.When I hit url like http://localhost/magento/{web-service-path}?SID=enjgmb9m8pq2ij2jq3vcr0vln5
Then Customer id comes in the collection like:

```
[visitor_data] => Array
            (
                [] => 
                [server_addr] => 2130706433
                [remote_addr] => 2130706433
                [http_secure] => 
                [http_host] => 127.0.0.1
                [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
                [http_accept_language] => en-US,en;q=0.5
                [http_accept_charset] => 
                [request_uri] => /magento/index.php/customer/account/index/
                [session_id] => ab3nt9gk9ql56u9p4kn74kf6p2
                [http_referer] => http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/customer/account/login/
                [first_visit_at] => 2015-09-29 05:31:43
                [is_new_visitor] => 
                [last_visit_at] => 2015-09-29 05:31:48
                [visitor_id] => 77
                [last_url_id] => 2069
                [do_customer_login] => 
                [customer_id] => 5907
                [customer_log_id] => 8
            )
```

But I dont want to show SID in url.So I want to know what magento do when we write SID in url.So that I can implement the same code for retrieving session data.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the following:

```
public function setSessionId($id=null)
    {
        if (is_null($id) && $this->useSid()) {
            $_queryParam = $this->getSessionIdQueryParam();
            if (isset($_GET[$_queryParam]) && Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->isOwnOriginUrl()) {
                $id = $_GET[$_queryParam];
            }
        }

        $this->addHost(true);
        return parent::setSessionId($id);
    }
```

source: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php#L376

This sets the session based on the query_params (SID) passed through the url. There is a constant at the top of this file that is the key for the session_id:
`const SESSION_ID_QUERY_PARAM = 'SID';`
source: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php#L52

Comment: Thanku so much.This seems relevant to me.Let me check it and get back to you.

Comment: ok, I have checked and find out that the function setSessionId() further calls the function setSessionId($id) in class app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php , which is ultimately using php function session_id($id); So to retrieve session data in code, I am using session_id(SID); session_start(); print_r($_SESSION); where SID id the session id already existing in magento for a customer. But I am getting empty session.I dont know why.

Comment: May be I am missing anything more that is necessary for getting session information.I am using same session id "enjgmb9m8pq2ij2jq3vcr0vln5" which is giving information on passing SID in url but not giving information on setting session id through function session_id().

Comment: Are you able to try just `session_id()` this should give you the session id being used. This should already be set via magento you should then just be able to use $_SESSION to access those variables if they are set. Do you know where the `visitor_data` is being set?

Comment: I am getting empty string in session_id() at first so that is why I am using session_id(SID) to set session_id.Visitor data is setting in file /app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.phpin function _saveVisitorInfo().

Comment: I noticed in the abstract varien class it does a preg_match before setting the session_id maybe try doing that with yours. `preg_match('#^[0-9a-zA-Z,-]+$#', $id)` source: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php#L270

Comment: Okay.But now I am using Cookie to retrieve customer id from session id.Magento sets cookie named 'frontend' with the SID value so i am using the same.So I am first setting the cookie and then on retrieving customer/session data I get customer id for that user.